# How to make a connection to a database via Massive

Tags: c#, massive

How to make a connection to a database via Massive?

There is a method in Massive for opening a connection, but it accepts name of a connection string. I want to give it the connection string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Massive code in Open() method is created DynamicModel and in DynamicModel constructor I found this line([Massive.cs](https://github.com/robconery/massive/blob/master/Massive.cs) 127 line):

```
ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
```

So that means you need to store connection string in configuration file and pass to Open method appropriated connection string name.

What you need is create overload methods to accept connection string. Here is an example:

```
public static DynamicModel Open(string connectionString, string providerName="System.Data.SqlClient") 
{
        dynamic dm = new DynamicModel(connectionString, providerName);
        return dm;
}

public DynamicModel(string connectionString, string providerName ="System.Data.SqlClient", string tableName = "", 
     string primaryKeyField = "", string descriptorField = "") 
{
        TableName = tableName == "" ? this.GetType().Name : tableName;
        PrimaryKeyField = string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryKeyField) ? "ID" : primaryKeyField;
        DescriptorField = descriptorField;

        _factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
}
```

Comment: Am I that unclear? I don't want to store the connection dtring in the config file. I want to pass the open method or some other method connection strin, not its name.

Comment: Cant you see in code that there is no method? You can easy create overload method that accepts connection string.